# Хочу запускать сервер через форму JFrame , но сервер винснет в ожидании

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, jframe

Хочу запускать сервер через форму `JFrame` по нажатию на кнопку `START`. После нажатия, сервер запускается. но виснет в ожидании клиента. Как убрать это ожидание?

Запустил сервер и клиенты подключаются, когда хотят. Я никого не жду и делаю своё.

```
public class ServerProgram extends JFrame {
    static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public static int sizeWidth = 800;
    public static int sizeHeight = 600;
    public static int locationX = (screenSize.width - sizeWidth) / 2;
    public static int locationY = (screenSize.height - sizeHeight) / 2;



    ServerProgram() {
        super("Server");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JButton startB = new JButton("Start");
        JButton stopB = new JButton("Stop");
        JButton portB = new JButton("Port");
        menuBar.add(startB);
        menuBar.add(stopB);
        menuBar.add(portB);

        startB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                         try {
                                             int i = 0;
                                             ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6666, 0,
                                                     InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));

                                             System.out.println("server is started");


                                             while (true) {
                                                 new NewConnection(i, server.accept());
                                                 i++;
                                             }
                                         } catch (Exception x) {
                                             System.out.println("init error: " + e);
                                         } 
                                     }
                                 });
}}


    public class NewConnection extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    int num;

    NewConnection(int num,Socket s)
    {
        this.num = num;
        this.s = s;

        setDaemon(true);
        setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // из сокета клиента берём поток входящих данных
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            // и оттуда же - поток данных от сервера к клиенту
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();

            // буффер данных в 64 килобайта
            byte buf[] = new byte[64*1024];
            // читаем 64кб от клиента, результат - кол-во реально принятых данных
            int r = is.read(buf);

            // создаём строку, содержащую полученную от клиента информацию
            String data = new String(buf, 0, r);

            // добавляем данные об адресе сокета:
            data = ""+num+": "+"\n"+data;

            // выводим данные:
            os.write(data.getBytes());

            // завершаем соединение
            s.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {System.out.println("init error: "+e);} // вывод исключений
    }
}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerProgram serP = new ServerProgram();
```

Comment: Сокет так же в отдельном потоке создавать желательно. И обработку новых коннектов - там же.

Comment: Вот четко в точку сказал, помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сокет так же в отдельном потоке создавать желательно. И обработку новых коннектов - там же.

Есть слушатель события:

```
new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
      int i = 0;
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6666, 0,
        InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));

      System.out.println("server is started");

      while (true) {
        new NewConnection(i, server.accept());
    i++;
      }
    } catch (Exception x) {
      System.out.println("init error: " + e);
    } 
  }
}
```

В нём производится создание сокета и запускается цикл отлова новых соединений.

Эти действия нужно поместить в отдельный поток, чтобы они не блокировали поток UI.

Самый простой способ - вот так:

```
new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Thread(()->{
      try {
        int i = 0;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6666, 0,
          InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));

        System.out.println("server is started");

        while (true) {
          new NewConnection(i, server.accept());
      i++;
        }
      } catch (Exception x) {
        System.out.println("init error: " + e);
      } 
    }).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: А потоки закрывать потом не надо если клиент отключится?

Comment: Чтобы они закрылись после завершения основного потока - иъ нужно демонизировать. `Thread thread = new Thread(()->{}); thread.setDaemon(true); thread.start();`